# Issues calling Youtube Api via Curl: CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT error

Tags: php, curl, youtube-api

I'm trying to delete a video by its ID via YoutubeAPi using curl.

In the following code curl_errno() returns CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT error.

```
$link = urlencode("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=my_Video_ID&key=my_API_KEY");

 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $test = curl_errno($ch);
    echo $test . "\n";
    $result = json_decode($result);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
```

What's wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to encode the URL (`urlencode`). Just assign the URL string to your `$link` variable. (Read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).)

However, it is good idea to encode the parameter values:

**test.php**

```
$id = urlencode('AAAAABBBCCC');
$key = urlencode('AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC');
$link = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$id&key=$key";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

*Testing*

```
php test.php
```

*Output*

```
string(238) "{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
"
```

The API actually works. Now you need to set the correct `id` and `key` parameters *and* the authorization token as described in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/#calling-the-api):

> You must send an authorization token for every insert, update, and
>   delete request.

Comment: Thanks for your help but still have the same issue.

Comment: @AugusteLarrivé, are you sure? I've updated the answer. Could you try to run the script exactly as it is written in the answer?

Comment: I run the script exactly as you and got the same answer

Comment: @AugusteLarrivé, the same as in the sample output, or the same `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT` error?

Comment: @AugusteLarrivé, then it is not the `CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT` error (the main question of your post) already, and we see that the API *actually works*. It doesn't perform your request because it needs authentication token (as I've written).

Comment: Oh I see thank you but it looks like I'm able to authenticate to Google but I don't get access token